# Intertwine lists without .zip import

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to link two lists like this:

a = [10,20,30]
b = [2,4,6]

--> [(10,2),(20,4),(30,6)]

then, but after implementing this code:

```
>>def zipped(a,b):
    >> for m in range(len(a)):
         >> for n in range(len(b)):
                >> return [(a[m],b[n])]
```

I only get this:

```
>>  [(10,2)]
```

How can I get the other values?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have nested loops, they would build the product of both lists, but since you're returning on the first iteration, you get just the first pair. What you want is something like:

```
def zip(fun, car):
    zipped = []
    for i in range(min((len(fun), len(car)))):
        zipped.append((fun[i], car[i]))
    return zipped
```

Or, a shorter version with list comprehensions:

```
def zip(fun, car):
    return [(fun[i], car[i]) for i in range(min((len(fun), len(car))))]
```